# How to access lowlevel API for storing data in Google App Engine for python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

What is the alternative for Entity.java in python version?
I do not want any data model. I want my entities without a predefined structure. I just want them to be key and value pairs as the above Entity.java is.

Can I do it in Python version?

Answer (score 6):

The 'low level' API is in google.appengine.api.datastore. There's no public documentation for it, but the module itself has fairly complete docstrings.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Expando](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/expandoclass.html) class.

```
class MyModel(db.Expando)
   pass
```

You can then add properties by simply setting the value.  And they can be removed too.

**edit:**
I should also have mentioned the [dynamic properties](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_is_saved) method.  It will return the list of properties defined for a particular entity.

Comment: It seems working. But Expando extends Model. Is there anything lower than Model that I can access?

Comment: If you want something lower level see Nick's reply.  Check out Tim's reply to this (http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-python/browse_thread/thread/a54bd7146045971/90a9f4f442665033) thread.  He gives an example of how you can directly access datastore objects as dictionaries.